# Print jag matrix with join and foreach

Tags: c#, join, foreach

I need to print jag matrix with only one foreach loop (I have ToString method).
I tried this code, but i got  not clear error:

```
class hw1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student[][] mat = new Student[][]
        {
        new Student[]{
            new Student(1, "Adi", new List<int>{1, 2, 3}),
            new Student(2, "Tam", new List<int>{101, 102, 103}),
        new Student[]{
            new Student(5, "tAss", new List<int>{91, 92, 93}),
        new Student[]{
            new Student(10, "Gal", new List<int>{}),
            new Student(11, "Fani", new List<int>{}),
        };

        Print(mat);
    }


    static void Print(Student[][] jag)
    {
        //Student[] studentArray = jag.Cast<Student>().ToArray();
        foreach (var s in jag)
        {
           string f = string.Join(" ", s);
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }
    }
```

This is the error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'string.Join(string, params object[])' and 'string.Join
>   (string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the compiler a little help - it can't infer which `Join` overload to use.

You probably want to use the overload with `IEnumerable<Student>`, so you can do this by explicitly stating the type of `s` as `IEnumerable<Student>` rather than `Student[]`:

```
foreach (IEnumerable<Student> s in jag)
{
    string f = string.Join(" ", s);
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! (I'm new at C#).